# Compile C# on OSX using edge.js nuget package

Tags: macos, nuget, edge.js

So, I have this code from the edge.js instructions:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EdgeJs;

class Program
{
    public static async void Start()
    {
        var func = Edge.Func(@"
            return function (data, callback) {
                callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + data);
            }
        ");

        Console.WriteLine(await func(".NET"));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run((Action)Start).Wait();
    }
}
```

And I have nuget working so that I have installed edge.js with `nuget install edge.js -o ./packages`

But I can't figure out how to compile it on my Mac OSX. I've tried:

```
mcs -pkg:./packages program.cs
mcs -lib:./packages/Edgejs.0.10.0 program.cs
```

and a bunch other combinations. I always get this error:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name `EdgeJs' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I have not tried monoDevelop yet. I'm hoping to get it to work with the mono command line tools so I don't need monoDevelop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -r to reference the Edgejs assembly.

```
mcs -r:./packages/Edge.js.0.10.0/lib/Edgejs.dll program.cs
```